# New key binding not implemented for the influence of proportional editing

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut, customization, selection-tools, proportional-editing

As I'm working on a laptop with a trackpad, and without a mouse, and I've re-assigned the key bindings to increase/decrease the influence for proportional editing to

- alt+page up (to increase)
- alt+page down (to decrease)

When I search key-bindings with "alt up arrow" in [Preferences > Keymap], I see that there is only one setting (the one I had just set).

[image]

Maybe the arrow keys are off-limits in some way, as I see that no matter what combination I set, the up/down keys continue to be used to incrementally move the curser up or down (when grabbing, for instance).

I'd love to know if there is a key-combination that I could use for this that doesn't conflict. Or maybe I'm not setting the new key-bindings correctly?

Thanks.